# How to access certain resources such as Doctrine or Request from an event listener in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

**Version**: Symfony 3

Issue: Accessing Resource from an event listener's method, such as "onKernelBefore".

I have the following method which gets called right before invocation of a controller:

```
function onKernelController(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent $controllerEvent)
    {
        $controller = $controllerEvent->getController();

        /*
         * $controller passed can be either a class or a Closure.
         * This is not usual in Symfony but it may happen.
         * If it is a class, it comes in array format
         */
        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }
        $Helper =  new Helper();
        $current_path = $Helper->cleanSlashes($controllerEvent->getRequest()->getPathInfo());



        if ($controller[0] instanceof RouteAuthenticateInterface) {
                print "Passed";
        }
    }
```

But I do not now how to access certain resources such as Doctrine or Request etc. I event have accessed my helper through direct instanciaion:

```
$Helper =  new Helper();
```

While it is common to access it from the controller like this:

```
$this->get("Helper");

For instance I can't access this:

$this->container
```

I know the pseudo-variable `$this` is referring to a resource other than a controller; but even when I use `$controller[0]->container` I bump into "protected property exception".

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Basically, you want to inject your helper into your listener.  Modify your listener service definition with arguments: ['@helper'] then add a constructor in your listener to receive it.  It is all documented.  And the request itself can be pulled from the event object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

...

 public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
....
```

Or a better example coming from the FOSUserBundle:

```
...
public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer, TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator, 
            UrlGeneratorInterface $router, SessionInterface $session, Container $container)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->tokenGenerator = $tokenGenerator;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->container = $container;
    }
...
```